# Ubuntu 21.10 - issues sharing folders to Windows 10

Tags: permissions, windows, nautilus, samba, shared-folders

Basically before a reinstall of Ubuntu 21.10 server, via Ubuntu Desktop I was able to right click on a folder > Local Network share and I was able to share.

I think my undoing is when I try share and i get the netutils share install service prompt it is not able to install, it gets "sharing service installation failed",
[netutils service error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIA5o.png

I tried checking through logs,

- G_DEBUG="all" NAUTILUS_DEBUG="All" nautilus
- /var/log/apt/term.log
- /var/log/dpkg.log

but it does not log any install errors, i tried elevating netutils with "admin:///usr/" and it didn't help.

As netutils does not install I

- installed samba "sudo apt-get install samba"
- Added my user to the  "sudo usermod -a -G sambashare myuser"
- Added passwords "sudo smbpasswd -a myuser"

I can add shares now, but get an access denied trying to access them via windows. Samba log looks like the following when i attempt to connect,

```
[2021/11/14 07:05:30.461707,  0] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:166(chdir_current_service)
  chdir_current_service: vfs_ChDir(/mnt/EMC3/OP) failed: Permission denied. Current token: uid=65534, gid=65534, 1 groups: 65534
[2021/11/14 07:05:30.461747,  3] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3861(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3147
[2021/11/14 07:05:30.462138,  4] ../../source3/smbd/vfs.c:939(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /mnt/EMC3/OP
```

should mentioned I did reboots thru each step, Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was windows 10 was hanging on to the connection from the previous install of ubuntu even though i disconnected the drives and cleared the creds from the cred vault. started working after a reboot of windows.